# How to solve coupled complex-valued equations faster and get simplified solution

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, complex

I have six coupled equations. How to solve these equations symbolically faster in Mathematica. In these equations, variables `p,q,x,y` are `Reals` and variables `a,b,c` are complex terms. These equations should be solved for `{R11, R22, R33, R21, R31, R32}`, but I want to only get the solution for `R21`.

```
eqns={ R11 + R22 + R33 == 1, 
p Im[R21] == R22 x + R33 y, 
q Im[R32] == R33 (y + z), 
(I p R11)/2 + a R21 - (I p R22)/2 + (I q R31)/2 == 0, 
(I q R21)/2 + b R31 - (I p R32)/2 == 0, 
(I q R22)/2 - (I p R31)/2 + c R32 - (I q R33)/2 == 0};

term = {R11, R22, R33, R21, R31, R32};
```

I can do the series expansion for q and p. I try to solve these equations as a series solution of p,q given here...

```
Series[R21 /. Solve[eqns, term], {p, 0, 3}, {q, 0, 3}] // Timing
```

Do you have better solution? I also need to define that variables `p,q,x,y` are `Reals` and variables `a,b,c` are complex.

Answer (score 4):

Edited to simplify the derivation and reduce the length of the final result.

If `R21` and `R32` are pure imaginary, then the equation is solved easily.

```
R21 /. Solve[eqns /. {Im[R21] -> -I R21, Im[R32] -> -I R32}, term][[1]]
(* (I p (2 b q^2 x + 2 b q^2 y - 4 b c x y - p^2 x y - 4 b c x z - 
   p^2 x z))/(6 b p^2 q^2 - 4 a b q^2 x - p^2 q^2 x - q^4 x - 
   8 b c p^2 y - 2 p^4 y - 4 a b q^2 y + 3 p^2 q^2 y - q^4 y + 
   8 a b c x y + 2 a p^2 x y + 2 c q^2 x y - 8 b c p^2 z - 2 p^4 z + 
   p^2 q^2 z + 8 a b c x z + 2 a p^2 x z + 2 c q^2 x z) *)
```

which indeed are pure imaginary, if all the parameters are real.

The general case also can be solved, although the result is lengthy.  Since the challenge here arises from the second and third of `eqns` and `R21` and `R32`, we begin by eliminating the other equations and variables.

```
Flatten[Solve[Delete[eqns, {{2}, {3}}], Delete[term, {{4}, {6}}]]];
s = Simplify[Delete[eqns, {{1}, {4}, {5}, {6}}] /. %]
(* {p Im[R21] == -((I ((q R21 - p R32) (p^2 (x - 2 y) + q^2 (x + y)) + 
    b (4 a q R21 (x + y) + p (-4 c R32 (x - 2 y) + 2 I q (x + y)))))/(6 b p q)), 
    q Im[R32] == -((I ((2 p^2 - q^2) (-q R21 + p R32) + 
    b (2 I p q + 4 a q R21 + 8 c p R32)) (y + z))/(6 b p q))} *)
```

Next, we Solve to obtain `R32` and then its imaginary part, and substitute both into the remaining equation.

```
Collect[Solve[s[[1]], R32][[1, 1, 2]], {R21, Im[R21]}, Simplify];
Im[%];
Simplify[s[[2]] /. {R32 -> %%, Im[R32] -> %}]
(* q (Im[(q R21 (p^2 (x - 2 y) + 4 a b (x + y) + q^2 (x + y)))/
   (p (4 b c (x - 2 y) + p^2 (x - 2 y) + q^2 (x + y)))] + 
   2 Re[(b q (x + y))/(4 b c (x - 2 y) + p^2 (x - 2 y) + q^2 (x + y))] - 
   6 Re[(b p q Im[R21])/(4 b c (x - 2 y) + p^2 (x - 2 y) + q^2 (x + y))]) ==
   -(((y + z) ((-p^3 + 2 I a p^2 R21 + 2 I c q^2 R21 - 4 b c (p - 2 I a R21)) x + p^2 
   (8 b c + 2 p^2 - q^2) Im[R21]))/(p (4 b c (x - 2 y) + p^2 (x - 2 y) + q^2 (x + y)))) *)
```

`Solve` and `Reduce` seem unable to solve this equation as written, so instead we treat the real and imaginary parts of `R21` as independent variables.

```
Simplify[% /. {Re[z_  Im[R21]] -> Re[z] R21i, Im[z_  R21] -> R21i Im[z] + R21r Re[z], 
    Im[R21] -> R21i} /. R21 -> R21r + I R21i]
Simplify[CoefficientArrays[%, {R21r, R21i}] // Normal];
Map[{R21r, R21i}.# &, Transpose[ReIm[%[[2]]]]] + ReIm[%[[1]]];
Simplify[%, (R21r | R21i | p | q | x | y | z) ∈ Reals];
Map[# == 0 &, %];
```

Finally, we solve for the real and imaginary parts and then reconstitute `R21`.

```
Simplify[(R21r + I R21i) /. Flatten[Solve[%, {R21r, R21i}]]]
```

The result, with a `LeafCount` of `1229`, is a bit long to be reproduced here.  The computations described above take only seconds, however.  Also, it seems likely that the final result can be simplified somewhat, given enough effort.

Comment: Final simplify gives me an error...Solve::naqs: (ReIm[-(((4 b c+p^2) x (y+z))/(Times[<<4>>]+Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>]))+2 q Re[b q Plus[<<2>>] Power[<<2>>]]]==0)+(Transpose[{R21r,R21i}.ReIm[{Times[<<6>>]+Times[<<2>>],Times[<<4>>]+Times[<<8>>]+Times[<<6>>]+Times[<<7>>]+Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<3>>]}]]==0) is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities. >>

Comment: Map[{R21r, R21i}.# &, Transpose[ReIm[%[[2]]]]] + ReIm[%[[1]]]; this line is not clear to me. What is ReIm[] here??

Comment: `ReIm[]` is the same as `{Re[],Im[]}`.  What version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: I am using Mathematica 9

Comment: `ReIm` is new to Mathematica 10.  Replace `ReIm[%[[2]]]` by `{Re[%[[2]]], Im[%[[2]]]}`.  I just tried it successfully.  Be sure to count brackets carefully!  Best wishes.

Comment: Your process it bit tricky for 10 equations.. {R11 + R22 + R33 + R44 == 1, 
p Im[R21] == 
 R22 x + R44 x1 + R33 y, -(1/2) I (R34 - R43) rf + q Im[R32] == 
 R33 (y + y1 + z), 
R33 y1 + rf Im[R43] == 
 R44 x1, (I p R11)/2 + a R21 - (I p R22)/2 + (I q R31)/2 == 0, (
  I q R21)/2 + b R31 - (I p R32)/2 + (I R41 rf)/2 == 0, 
a1 R41 - (I p R42)/2 + (I R31 rf)/2 == 0, (I q R22)/2 - (I p R31)/2 + 
  c R32 - (I q R33)/2 + (I R42 rf)/2 == 0, -(1/2) I p R41 + b1 R42 - (
  I q R43)/2 + (I R32 rf)/2 == 0, -(1/2) I q R42 + c1 R43 + (
  I R33 rf)/2 - (I R44 rf)/2 == 0}

Comment: Variable are {R11, R22, R33, R44, R21, R31, R41, R32, R42, R43}. Can be generalize you process. Even though...Thank you very much for your efforts...

Comment: @Santosh  The addition of a third variable for which `I'm` appears explicitly certainly is more complicated.  Nonetheless, the process I used above should work.  The results may be very lengthy, however.